# Django ajax not working on multiple href inside for loop of jinja2 template

Tags: javascript, html, django, jinja2

I am working on ajax based message system using Django. I have Rooms and Messages in those rooms. The basic idea is on the left side there will be rooms by the user and on the right side there will be detail view of one particular room. Ajax is used to view each rooms message.

```
<div class="inbox_chat">
          {% for room in rooms %}
            <div class="chat_list">
              <div class="chat_people">
                <a href="#" id="view_message" data-catid="{{ room.id }}">
                    <div class="chat_img"> <img src="https://ptetutorials.com/images/user-profile.png"> </div>
                    <div class="chat_ib">
                      <h5>{{room.course}} <span class="chat_date">{{room.timestamp}}</span></h5>
                      <p>{{room.messages.last.message}}</p>
                      <small>by <strong>{{room.messages.last.sender}}</strong></small>
                    </div>
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          {% endfor %}
          </div>
```

above is the jinja code for displaying the rooms. I am facing problem in href tag. I can click on first result of for loop, but nothing happens on the second result of for loop.

My Javascript code:

```
{% block script %}
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#view_message').on('click', function(e){
            var BASE_URL = window.location.origin + window.location.pathname;
            console.log(BASE_URL);
            var room_id = $(this).attr("data-catid");
            console.log(room_id);
            $.ajax({
                url: BASE_URL + "view_message/",
                method: 'GET',
                data: {
                    room_id: room_id
                }
            });
        });
    });
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: please add more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`id` attributes are supposed to be unique in the entire HTML page. jQuery only returns the first element when you use the `#...` selector. Use a class or a data attribute instead of an `id` attribute.